# com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41 is incompatible on Weblogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: java, jaxb, weblogic12c, unmarshalling

***com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.7-b41 is incompatible on Weblogic 12.2.1.3***

We upgraded our Weblogic from version 12.1.3 to 12.2.1.3.

jaxb is working perfectly on 12.1.3 but in 12.2.1.3 the xml getting cut.

For example the expected xml is:

```
<![CDATA[ns3:findSomethingResponse xmlns:ns2=".....
```

but what we are getting is like this:

```
<![CDATA[ingResponse xmlns:ns2=".....
```

Can someone help us on this?

Thanks!

Comment: i have similar issue, did you find any solution ?